# Enum name generation nswag and swashbuckle

Tags: c#, swashbuckle, .net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, nswagstudio

I have a Web API that uses `swashbuckle` to generate swagger ui and json to code generation.The problem is that when I generate the code with `nswag studio` it doesn't generate enums in proper format. let me explain more clearly. My enum that is created like this in back end:

```
public enum OrderType
{
    ASC = 0,
    DESC = 1,
    None = 2,
}
```

but the result that i get with `nswag studio` code generator is like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
public enum OrderInfoOrderType
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"None")]
    None = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"ASC")]
    ASC = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"DESC")]
    DESC = 2,

}
```

my start up code is like this:

```
services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        });
```

What have I done wrong here?. I'm using `.net core 3.1`.

Comment: Ouch smells like a bug, can you post your swagger.json?

Answer (score 1):

I was testing this with my test API and I have this enum:

```
    public enum CustomEnum
    {
        Text = 1,
        Numeric = 2,
        Date = 4,
        Numeric_Function = 8,
        Dropdown_List = 16,
        Checkbox = 32
    }
```

https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/TestEnumController.cs

and the generated `nswag studio` looks like:

```
/// <summary>CustomEnum</summary>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
public enum Value4
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Text")]
    Text = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Numeric")]
    Numeric = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Date")]
    Date = 2,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Numeric_Function")]
    Numeric_Function = 3,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Dropdown_List")]
    Dropdown_List = 4,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Checkbox")]
    Checkbox = 5,

}
```

but on the swagger json there is no indication of the values for the enum:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1

```
"/api/TestEnum": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "TestEnum"
    ],
    "summary": "Simple GET echoing the given param",
    "operationId": "TestEnum_Get",
    "consumes": [],
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "text/json",
      "text/html"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "value",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "CustomEnum",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "Text",
          "Numeric",
          "Date",
          "Numeric_Function",
          "Dropdown_List",
          "Checkbox"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I think that just works fine like that and the numeric values on the client do not matter.

You can see the whole swagger here:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=TestEnum#/TestEnum/TestEnum_Get